# Android multiple Progressbar Instances not updating correctly

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-progressbar, android-viewbinding

I have a CustomView that has a progress bar in it. The custom view has a progress bar with a title and text progress as "1/5". I use this CustomView (ProgressBadgeWidget) in several places, including twice in my item layout for a RecyclerView (item_levels.xml - simplified for this):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

>

<com.trala.learn.violin.view.core.widgets.ProgressBadgeWidget
    android:id="@+id/courses_done_progress_widget"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:badge_image="@drawable/trophy_gold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background_image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/background_image"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.18"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.12"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/background_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background_image"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.96"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.24"
    app:progress_badge_title="@string/courses_done"
    app:progress_bar_background_color="@color/progress_bar_background_default"
    app:progress_text_color="@color/progress_bar_background_course_header"

    />


<com.trala.learn.violin.view.core.widgets.ProgressBadgeWidget
    android:id="@+id/medals_earned_progress_widget"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:badge_image="@drawable/medal_gold_small"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background_image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/background_image"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.18"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.85"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/background_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background_image"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.96"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.24"
    app:progress_badge_title="@string/medals_earned"
    app:progress_bar_background_color="@color/progress_bar_background_default"
    app:progress_bar_foreground_color="@color/progress_bar_default_color"
    app:progress_text_color="@color/progress_bar_background_course_header" />
```

The xml layout for the ProgressBadgeWidget is below:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
tools:parentTag="com.trala.learn.violin.view.core.widgets.ProgressBadgeWidget">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/badge_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_family"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:letterSpacing="-0.04"
    android:textColor="@color/courses_badge_text_color"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:lineHeight="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/badge_image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

    />

<com.trala.learn.violin.view.core.widgets.EZColorProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_badge_widget_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.10"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.90"
    tools:progress="50" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/badge_image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/progress_badge_widget_progress_bar"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/progress_badge_widget_progress_bar"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/progress_badge_widget_progress_bar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/progress_badge_widget_progress_bar"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.27"
    tools:src="@drawable/trophy_gold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_family"
    android:textColor="@color/courses_badge_text_color"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/badge_image"
    tools:text="4/7" />
```

Pretty simple, as described before. Main part is the EZColorProgressBar, which is a subclassed ProgressBar just providing ways to change bar colors and a method to set progress and max:

```
 class EZColorProgressBar @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal, defStyleRes: Int = 0):
            ProgressBar(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {


fun setProgressNumbers(currentCount: Int, totalCount: Int) {
        if (currentCount > totalCount) Timber.d("Current Badge Count > Total Badge Count")

        val shouldShowBadges = currentCount >= totalCount && (currentCount != 0 && totalCount != 0)
        showBadge(shouldShowBadges)

        viewBinding?.progressBadgeWidgetProgressBar?.setMax(totalCount)
        viewBinding?.progressBadgeWidgetProgressBar?.setProgress(currentCount)
        viewBinding?.progressText?.setText(String.format(context.getString(R.string.score_string), currentCount, totalCount))


      }
}
```

I use the ProgressBadgeWidget and EZProgressBar on almost all of my Fragments. When I go between fragments and navigate backwards, the progress bars are not always showing their numbers correctly, ie the first time 0/5 will show correctly, then navigating to other pages that use this EZProgressBar and navigate back will show 1/5 even if the text has 0/5.

First navigation:
 [image]

After: data model backing progress bar is correct (you can see from the 0/5 being correct). Looks like it's applying the 3/11 from the other progress bar

[image]

When this happens it actually applies the incorrect progress bar numbers to all progress bars in the layout (ie every progress bar in all items of item_level in the recyclerview adapter and even in a separate fragment so it's not tied to the recyclerview.) But again all of the text "x/x" shows correctly.

I've tried using kotlin synthetics bindings and google view bindings. It feels like the separate instances of the progress bars (they are separate as I've printed out the hashcodes) they are pointing at the same progress bar because it's searching for views based on IDs. The ProgressBadgeWidgets have unique ID's but their nested progress bars have the same IDs.

Has anyone come across issues like this and/or specifically with Android Progress Bars?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes upon an issue with multiple progress bars not updating properly, seems there is a big Android bug related to this. Way to solve it is to explicitly change/reset the max and progress values before setting to your correct numbers. I added these methods to my custom progress bar:

```
fun setProgressSafely(progress: Int) {
    setProgress(progress + 1)
    setProgress(progress)
}

fun setMaxSafely(max: Int) {
    setMax(max + 1)
    setMax(max)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used regular progress bar but with a layer-list xml as progressDrawable. Sometimes the end of the circular progress bar didn't update its location but used the location of another recycled view's value. I worked around it with using `mutate()`:

```
item.progress?.let {
    holder.mProgressLabel.text = String.format(context.getString(R.string.progress_label), it * 100)
    holder.mProgressView.progress = Math.round(it * 100).toInt()
    (holder.mProgressView.progressDrawable as LayerDrawable?)?.apply {
        mutate()
    }
}
```